# BigQuery generated table from gSheet is unaccessible through JDBC driver

Tags: google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, cognos-bi

I'm trying to connect BigQuery to a BI Tool (Cognos Analytics) through a JDBC driver.
It all works OK, until I try to read a gSheet generated table. Then I get the following error:

```
Data source adapter error: java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100033) Error getting job status. 
[Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100033) Error getting job status. 
[Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100033) Error getting job status. 
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Error while reading table: <GSHEET-TABLE>, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Error code: PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Error while reading table: <GSHEET-TABLE>, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Error code: PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

My connection string is the following:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=<MY-PROJECT-ID>;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=<CLIENT-EMAIL-FROM-JSON>;OAuthPvtKeyPath=<PATH-TO-JSON>;Timeout=60; RequestGoogleDriveScope=1;
```

The Service Account has full Admin ownership of the entire project.
Does somebody know how to access gSheets generated tables?

Comment: Try opening up the gsheet and sharing it with the service account's email.

Comment: I've tried, it makes no difference.
When you say "sertice account's email" do you refer to the "client_email" that appears on the JSON?